# Juju 2.0 and LXD Remote Provider

Tags: juju, remote, lxd

It is possible to add a remote LXD provider in the new version of Juju (2.0-rc3-xenial-amd64)?

What I've tried till now:

- manual cloud

(it works if I use `juju deploy mysql --to lxd:<Machine's ID>` but I cannot deploy bundles)

- changed the default LXC remote provider:

enable https on remote and set up a password

`lxc remote add <name> <provider's IP address>`

`lxc remote set-default <name>`

(`lxc launch` works just fine, but Juju is still use the local provider)

- tried to add a new LXD cloud using a config yaml file, just like the one below

  `clouds:
  mylxd:
  type: lxd
  auth-types: [access-key, userpass]
  regions:
  deployment:
  endpoint: https://<Remote IP Address>:8443/1.0`

(but I cannot bootstrap using this particular cloud configuration)

Can you help me, please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The lxd provider that comes with Juju 2.0 will only create containers on the host machine.

The team has discussed using remote lxd machines, but for now, the lxd provider is a developer tool and just creates containers on the host.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! So, at this moment, I cannot install LXD on a different machine and connect it to Juju which is, let's say, on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using juju >= 2.1

SSH into the remote server (e.g. 192.168.10.2) and configure lxd to accept incoming connections and set a password.

```
(192.168.10.2)$ lxc config set core.https_address "[::]"
(192.168.10.2)$ lxc config set core.trust_password some-secret-string
```

Now in the machine where juju commands will be ran (A.K.A. juju client) add the remote lxd daemon, this is done to easily get the server's certificate.

```
(juju-client)$ lxc remote add 192.168.10.2 \
    --accept-certificate \
    --password=some-secret-string
```

Create a yaml configuration file that will be used by juju to add the cloud, this is how it should look like.

```
# file: some-remote.yaml
clouds:
  some-remote:
    type: lxd
    auth-types: [interactive, certificate]
    regions:
      some-remote:
        endpoint: 192.168.10.2
```

Add the cloud definition to juju:

```
(juju-client)$ juju add-cloud some-remote some-remote.yaml
```

Create the credentials.yaml file:

```
# file: credentials.yaml
some-remote:
  some-remote:
    auth-type: certificate
    client-cert: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      ...
      INSERT THE CONTENT OF ~/.config/lxc/client.crt
      ...
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    client-key: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      ...
      INSERT THE CONTENT OF ~/.config/lxc/client.key
      ...
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    server-cert: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      ...
      INSERT THE CONTENT OF ~/.config/lxc/client.crt
      ...
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Add the credentials to juju:

```
(juju-client)$ juju add-credential some-remote -f credentials.yaml
```

Verify the cloud was added correctly:

```
(juju-client)$ juju clouds
Cloud           Regions  Default          Type            Description
[...]
localhost             1  localhost        lxd             LXD Container Hypervisor
some-remote           1  some-remote      lxd             LXD Container Hypervisor
[...]
```

Bootstrap a new controller using the added cloud provider

```
(juju-client)$ juju bootstrap some-remote
```

Once the bootstrap is done, verify the controller was correctly spun in the remote lxd daemon:

```
(juju-client)$ lxc list 192.168.10.2:
+---------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+------------+-----------+
|     NAME      |  STATE  |              IPV4              | IPV6 |    TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
+---------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+------------+-----------+
| juju-ec8b3d-0 | RUNNING | 192.168.10.42 (eth0)           |      | PERSISTENT | 0         |
+---------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+------------+-----------+
(juju-client)$ juju status -m controller
Model       Controller   Cloud/Region             Version
controller  snowspeeder  snowspeeder/snowspeeder  2.1.2

App  Version  Status  Scale  Charm  Store  Rev  OS  Notes

Unit  Workload  Agent  Machine  Public address  Ports  Message

Machine  State    DNS            Inst id        Series  AZ  Message
0        started  192.168.10.42  juju-ec8b3d-0  xenial      Running
```

<sub>Source: http://tty.cl/add-remote-lxd-server-as-a-cloud-in-juju-2x.html</sub>

<sub>disclaimer: I'm the author of the referenced article</sub>